# Is it possible to nest any DOM elements inside of an option element?

Tags: html

I realize that nesting in an option element (aside from `optgroup`) is a violation of w3c standards. However, are there *any* elements which do not violate this standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Its [content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-models) is [text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#text-content).

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had been looking around at posts and a different w3c article but this one is pretty spot on.

Comment: The HTML5 spec is **the** authoritative source for this kind of information.

Comment: HTML5 is work in progress, and no HTML5 draft is authoritative. All HTML recommendations by the W3C, such as HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0, specify that the content of `option` is just text, though.

Answer (score 1):

By HTML syntax rules, you cannot nest any element inside `option`. (You can nest `option` inside `optgroup`, but that’s a different issue.)

Browsers enforce this: they discard any tags inside `option`. You can see this by testing with `<option>foo <em>bar</em></option>` and looking at the document e.g. with Firebug.

However, it is *possible* to insert DOM elements inside an `option` element with scripting, e.g.

```
<option id=foo>
...
<script>
  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'Hello <em>world</em>';
</script>
```

This is not particularly useful, since browsers impose severe restrictions on styling the content of `option` elements. Of the browsers I tested, only Firefox renders the `em` element in this context in its usual way for `em` (in italic) and lets me set e.g. its color and background in CSS.

And, of course, playing with the DOM in a manner that violates HTML rules is somewhat risky.